Dealing with NULL when using aggregate function in QGIS Expression
How to deal with NULL in QGIS expressions when using aggregate functions such as union?
E.g.:
geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1,4), make_point(1,2))) ----> 'MultiPoint ((1 4),(1 2))'

geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1,4), NULL))            ----> NULL

geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1,4), make_point(1,4))) ----> 'Point (1 4)'

In the second situation, how could I still get either the same results as the third one or MultiPoint ((1 4))?
The same goes with collect_geometries.

You can replace NULL with empty geometry, e.g.
geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1, 4), if(is_empty_or_null(make_point(1,2)), geom_from_wkt('POINT()'), make_point(1,2))))
--> 'MultiPoint ((1 4),(1 2))'

geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1, 4), if(is_empty_or_null(NULL), geom_from_wkt('POINT()'), NULL)))
--> 'MultiPoint ((1 4))'

geom_to_wkt(union(make_point(1, 4), if(is_empty_or_null(make_point(1,4)), geom_from_wkt('POINT()'), make_point(1,4))))
--> 'Point (1 4)'

It does still produce a MultiPoint where this may not be expected. That's unlikely to be an issue since you're doing a union that is already expected to produce MultiPoint in this example.

One way is to use array_remove_all to actually remove all NULL values from an array before using collect_geometries:
geom_to_wkt( 
    collect_geometries(
        array_remove_all(
             array(
                make_point(1,2),
                NULL
            ),
            value:=NULL
        )
    )
)
----> 'MultiPoint ((1 2))'

Note: It doesn't work with union.
